# Why is MySQL not connecting when reading from mylogin.cnf?

Tags: linux, configuration, connections

On Ubuntu 20.04, I can log into a server by specifying the log credentials on the CLI:

```
$ mysql -h172.30.0.2 -uroot -p bar -e "SELECT id FROM users LIMIT 1;"
Enter password:
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  1 |
+----+
```

However, I cannot log in when using `~/.mylogin.cnf`:

```
$ cat ~/.mylogin.cnf
[foo]
user=root
password="notTheRealPassword"
host=172.30.0.2

$ mysql --login-path=foo bar -e "SELECT id FROM users LIMIT 1;"
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

I have confirmed that the file is being read by changing the permissions of the file and noticing MySQL complaining:

```
$ chmod 660 ~/.mylogin.cnf

$ mysql --login-path=foo bar -e "SELECT id FROM users LIMIT 1;"
mysql: [Warning] /home/dotancohen/.mylogin.cnf should be readable/writable only by current user.
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

**Why might MySQL not connect when using `~/.mylogin.cnf`?** How should I debug why MySQL is not connecting?

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug [here](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=93996).

You can check your `.conf` file permissions.

The root cause of crashes or other unexpected behavior will be in the error logs. The default path of the MySQL log file is `/var/log/mysql/error.log` on Ubuntu.

Also for debugging check this [out](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/debugging-server.html).

Comment: Thank you Yunus, but that bug is not what the problem is here. That bug allows one to connect even though the file permissions are wrong. I cannot connect, even though the file permissions are correct. I just changed the file permissions to demonstrate that the `~/.mylogin.conf` file is in fact being read.